# First Timer struggling to install Wubi

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7, wubi

I'm trying to use Ubuntu for the first time here.  Trying to install 12.04 using the wubi file (following these instructions: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows ), but at step 7 (the end), when I select Ubuntu the screen glitches out, shows a bunch of twitching colours, and then the screen goes to black and the computer stops responding.  I don't really know what I'm doing and have no idea how to fix this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

My computer is currently using Windows 7, ACPI x64-based PC, AMD Radeon HD 6670, ACER AL1916W monitor.

Comment: Try the 64 bit version of the installation media, if you have.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a graphic driver problem.  But boot problem can be  caused by your Windows filesystem being corrupt.  First check your Windows disk by following the directions [**here**](http://www.w7forums.com/use-chkdsk-check-disk-t448.html)
Then tyro to boot into Ubuntu.
If that doesn't work here is how to try to get booted into Ubuntu and Install the drivers for your Radeon card.

On the boot screen, highlight Ubuntu and then press f8, it should give you several options.  The one most likely to work is "nomodeset"  If this works, Ubuntu will boot into low graphics mode.  If it boots, press your Windows(super) key and the type driver, the program "Additional Drivers" will come up, click on it with your mouse to open it.  It should automatically search for proprietary driver and hopefully find the one needed for you AMD Radeon card.  If it does install the version listed as "stable" first and try to reboot.  If the drivers work, you will boot into Ubuntu, if it doesn't repeat the "nomodeset" booting  process., **UNINSTALL THE PROPRIETY DRIVERS YOU INSTALLED FIRST**.  Then reboot with "nomodeset" and try again with one of the other drivers.